# The isometric immersion of a positively curved projective plane in 3-dimensional Euclidean space?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

In 1903, W. Boy showed that the real projective plane $\mathbb{R}P^2$ can be immersed in the Euclidean space $\mathbb{E}^3$ (see Werner Boy, Math. Ann. 57 (1903), no. 2, 151-184.). Suppose a Riemannian surface ($\mathbb{R}P^2$, g) has positive sectional curvature $K(x)$ everywhere. $K(x)$ needs not to be a constant. The question is: can this surface isometrically immersed in $\mathbb{E}^3$. I guess that there is no such an immersion. But I did not find a relative reference or a direct proof by myself.

As is well known that D. Hilbert proved that a hyperbolic plane can not be isometrically immersed in $\mathbb{E}^3$ (see D. Hilbert, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 2 (1901), no. 1, 87-99.). This is the motivation of the above problem.

Comment: I don’t think so: the immersion of the double cover of the sphere would be locally convex, hence globally convex, hence embedded. Or more easily, the projective plane would have a well-defined normal from mean-curvature, giving a section of the normal bundle. But since the pullback of the tangent bundle to R^3 is trivial, this would give a contradiction to the tangent bundle to RP^2 being nontrivial.

Comment: Ian is correct.  In fact, the open problem is whether $\mathbb{RP}^2$ can be immersed in $\mathbb{R}^4$ so that the induced metric has non-negative curvature.  (It can be *embedded* in $\mathbb{R}^4$ smoothly, and it can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^5$ with a metric of positive curvature, in fact with constant positive curvature.)

Comment: If you allow immersions which are only C^1, you can use the Nash-Kuiper theorem to deform Boy's embedding to an isometric one.

Comment: To Robert: Are there any references related to your statements? Thank you.

Comment: To Thomas: I am not very clear how the curvature becomes positive as the surface deforms?

Comment: @LaiyuanGao:  I don't know any recent references.  There is an embedding of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^5$, equivariant under an irreducible representation of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ on $\mathbb{R}^5$, that has constant (positive) Gauss curvature.  Gromov, in his 1986 book, Partial Differential Relations, asks whether $\mathbb{RP}^2$ can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^4$ with positive Gauss curvature (p. 279, Question (e'')).   I saw a preprint in 2005 that claimed to construct such an immersion, but it had a serious error and was never published, as far as I know.  That's all I know.

Comment: @IanAgol: Is the 2-fold sphere you mentioned is an immersion of the projective plane into $R^3$?

Comment: @RobertBryant: Thank you for your references. If  $RP^2$ can be immersed into $R^3$ with positive Gauss curvature then it seems that it can be embedded into $R^4$ with positive Gauss curvature by a deformation of that immersion in $R^3$ to an embeding in $R^4$ via removing self-intersections? I am not very sure.

Comment: @LaiyuanGao:  Are you interested in $C^1$ isometric immersions or only interested in isometric immersions that are at least $C^2$ (or some other regularity).  If you are satisfied with a $C^1$ isometric immersion, then, yes, by Nash-Kuiper, there is a $C^1$-isometric immersion of $(\mathbb{RP}^2,g)$ into $\mathbb{E}^3$ (as Thomas Richard said).  However, if the immersion is to be everywhere $C^2$, then the metric $g$ cannot have positive Gausß curvature everywhere, as Ian Agol's argument shows. About the $C^1$ deformation to an embedding in $\mathbb{R}^4$ question, I am not sure.

Comment: @IanAgol: Now I understand your comment. Forget my above question. Thank you.

Comment: @RobertBryant: Thank you for your clarification. I considered the immersion which is everywhere $C^2$.  Should a locally convex surface be globally convex? In fact, we have lots of closed and locally convex curves in the plane not embedded.

Comment: @RobertBryant: Understand. Due to Hadamard's theorem. Thanks.

Comment: @LaiyuanGao:  That's true, but it can't happen for a compact surface in $3$-space if the Gauß curvature is positive everywhere.  As Ian pointed out, the surface would have to be orientable, and then the Gauss map will make the surface into a covering space of the sphere, which ensures (if the surface is connected) that the surface is a $2$-sphere and that the Gauß map is 1-to-1.  (This is what is different from the locally-convex-curves-in-the-plane case.)

Answer (score 3):

Ian's argument of mean curvature is wonderfully simple. Here is another one. Rotate your surface to put it in generic position with respect to the heigth function z; then, the preimage of z is a Morse function f on RP^2, which has no critical point of index 1 (saddle point) since the surface is locally convex. Hence, every critical point of f has index 0 or 2 (local extremum). By Morse theory (or by the Poincaré-Hopf formula applied to a gradient-like vector field), the number of local extrema is the Euler characteristic of RP^2, hence 1. This is a contradiction, since there are at least one minimum and one maximum.